# Which nosql solution fits my application HBase OR Hypertable OR Cassandra

Tags: nosql, cassandra, hbase, hypertable

I have an application with 100 million of data and growing. I want to scale out before it hits the wall.

I have been reading stuff about nosql technologies which can handle Big Data efficiently.

My needs:

There are more reads than writes.But writes are also significantly large in numbers (read:write=4:3)

Can you please explain difference among HBase, Hypertable and Cassandra? Which one fits my requirements?

Comment: Your question is not a good fit for SO. I will also say that 100 million rows is not a substantial amount of data for any reasonable persistence storage mechanism whether NoSQL or RDBMs. You'd also need to clarify the requires such as picking two from Availability, Consistency, and Partition Tolerance.

Comment: why is it not a good fit...May be because SO fails in Availability, Consistency and Partition Tolerance

Comment: It is not a good fit because SO is about solving coding issues. Higher level design issues is better suited at programmers.stackexchange.com. If your question is moved there it would help to clarify some of the characteristics if storage you need.

Comment: I do not know much about HBase or Hypertable but we are using Cassandra and inserting more than 200 millions of records per day.We load this data at once in a day and works fine for us.

Answer (score 1):

Both HBase and Hypertable require hadoop. If you're not using Hadoop anyway (e.g. need to solve map/reduce related problems) - I'd go with cassandra as it is stand-alone

Answer (score 0):

If you already having data [Hive](http://hive.apache.org/) is the best solution for your application, Or you develop app from the scratch look into below link that explain overview of the nosql world

http://nosql-database.org/

http://www.vineetgupta.com/2010/01/nosql-databases-part-1-landscape/